# variable assignment in conditional after && (C)

Tags: c, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I am curious about the exact definition of the C standard about variable assignment within a conditional clause. Here is a small example:

```
int foo() {
  ...
}

int bar() {
  ...
}

int main () {
  int a, b, x, y;
  ...
  if ( (a = foo()) == x && (b = bar() == y ) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

A test with GCC revealed that if `(a = foo()) != x`, `b = bar()` will not be executed. On the one hand this behavior is optimal, as it will not waste any time with the calculation of `bar()`. On the other hand, though, the value of `b` is somewhat undefined, because it depends on the result of `foo()`, which actually has nothing to do with `b`.

I wonder if there is an explicit definition for such cases in the C standard and what the reasons for that definition would be. And finally, what is considered to be *best practice* for writing such code?

Comment: Look up "short circuit evaluation"

Comment: Which cases? Please elaborate.

Comment: If the code after the `if` depends on `b` being initialized, then the "best practice" is to not do like that.

Comment: Match brackets please.

Comment: Some flavour of this question has been asked a 100 times before on SO. Please do some research before posting. To the people who answered anyway, please close vote instead, a list of canonical dupes can be found in the [SO C tag wiki FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info).

Comment: Short-circuiting of `&&` and `||` is very common in computer languages in general, and is well-documented behavior in C.  In fact, in `a && b`, the compiler is *forbidden* from evaluating `b` if `a` is false (at least, insofar as observable side-effects are concerned).  This is something beginning C programmers typically learn in their first week of coding in C.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple: the second (i.e. right hand) argument of `&&` will **not** be evaluated if the first argument evaluates to 0.

So, `(b = bar() == y )` will **not** be evaluated if `(a = foo()) == x` is 0.

The fact that this could leave `b` uninitialised - with potentially undefined results - is a touchstone for the fact that you ought not code this way.

You *could* use

```
if ((a = foo() == x) & (b = bar() == y))
```

if you want both sides to always be evaluated: `&` is not short-circuited. But beware of unexpected effects if the arguments can evaluate to something other than 0 or 1 (which they don't in this case).

Answer (score 0):

> *A test with GCC revealed that if (a = foo()) != x, b = bar() will not be executed.*

Well, that's the property of the logical AND (`&&`) operator.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.13, *emphasis mine*

> Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation;
>   if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of
>   the first and second operands. **If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated.**

That said, for the *assignment* of `b`, you're right, if the first operand is FALSE, the value of `b` remains indeterminate and any usage of the variable may lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

(One of the) The *best practice*, is to initialize local variables upon definition to avoid use of indeterminate value.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `&&` consists of *short circuit evaluation*: the second subexpression is only evaluated if its result is needed in order to determine the result of the whole expression.

---

In your example, in the expression:

```
(a = foo()) == x && (b = bar() == y)
```

if the first subexpression `(a = foo()) == x` is evaluated to false, the result of the expression above is also false regardless of the result that the subexpression `(b = bar() == y)` would produce.

Because of both short-circuit evaluation and the fact that `(a = foo()) == x` evaluates to false, the expression `(b = bar() == y)` is never evaluated.